# Returning a pointer to a structure from function

Tags: c, struct, memcpy

I use some library which declares some opaque types. I wrapped this type into my own structure to abstract over this library opaque type and got some problem. Here is code:

```
typedef struct my_struct my_struct;
struct my_struct{
    opaque_lib_t *const opaque_lib_ptr; //opaque_lib_t is the opaque type
                                        //came from the library
};

my_struct* initialize(){
    opaque_lib_t *opaque_lib_ptr;
    init(&opaque_lib_ptr);              //library function call
    return opaque_lib_ptr;
}

void use_and_release(my_struct *my_struct_ptr){
     //use and release my_struct
}

my_struct *my_struct_ptr =  initialize();
use_and_release(my_struct_ptr);         //crashes
```

In such an implementation the call to `use_and_release` crashes. So I tried to replace `my_struct* initialize` with the following implementation

```
my_struct* initialize(){
     opaque_lib_t *opaque_lib_ptr;
     init(&opaque_lib_ptr);
     my_struct *my_struct_ptr = malloc(sizeof(*my_struct_ptr));
     my_struct tmp = {.opaque_lib_ptr = opaque_lib_ptr};
     memcpy(my_struct_ptr, &tmp, sizeof(tmp));
     return my_struct_ptr;
}
```

With such an implementation it works fine. But I don't understand why the first did not work. I thought that the pointer to a structure and the pointer to its first element has the same value. So in this case it should be fine to just return `opaque_lib_t*` and cast it to `my_struct*` since `my_struct*` contains only one element.

Comment: For your first piece of code to work, the member `opaque_lib_ptr` should be an instance of the structure `opaque_lib_t` instead (emulating a kind of inheritance), which considering the names would probably not be possible.

Comment: As for your second attempt, the `tmp` structure isn't needed. Just do `my_struct_ptr->opaque_lib_ptr = opaque_lib_ptr;` (after checking that the `malloc` call succeeded of course).

Comment: And if `my_struct` only contains that single member, why have the structure to begin with? What problem is the structure supposed to solve that using the `opaque_lib_t` pointer directly wont?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude _What problem is the structure supposed to solve that using the opaque_lib_t pointer directly wont?_ In my code I want to abstract over the specific library structures.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude _As for your second attempt, the tmp structure isn't needed._ the pointer is a `const` so such an assignment is not possible.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I understand the problem, thanks!

Comment: Ah yes itt's `const`. Then you need to go through the extra copying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you try to do with your first example is kind of attempting to emulating inheritance from object-oriented languages. It seems like you want `my_struct` to have an "is a" relationship with `opaque_lib_t`.

However that won't work because then you need the first member of `my_struct` to be an actual *instance* of the `opaque_lib_t` structure, i.e. it should be

```
struct my_struct{
    opaque_lib_t opaque_lib_instance;   //opaque_lib_t is the opaque type
                                        //came from the library
};
```

If `opaque_lib_t` really is an anonymous and opaque structure similar to `FILE` then that's not possible.

Another way of looking at is like this:

In memory `my_struct` will look something like

```
my_struct             opaque_lib_t
+----------------+    +-------------------+
| opaque_lib_ptr | -> | Unknown data      |
+----------------+    | More unknown data |
                      | ...               |
                      +-------------------+
```

You simply can't overlay `opaque_lib_t` on top of `my_struct`.

And when you do `return opaque_lib_ptr;` you effectively are saying that "this pointer is pointing to a `my_struct` whose first member is a pointer to `opaque_lib_t`". And that is simply wrong because those are two very different structure.

Continuing with the first piece of code, if you try to use `my_struct_ptr->opaque_lib_ptr` then the memory you access is the initial data of the `opaque_lib_t` structure (whose pointer you returned).

---

Lastly about what you say

> In my code I want to abstract over the specific library structures

I can understand that, but that's already the purpose of `opaque_lib_t`. You add an (unnecessary) abstraction on top of an abstraction.

I could understand your structure if it collected *multiple* related data, but not only the `opaque_lib_t` pointer.

Comment: Thanks, understood. But just one question. So if I replace the `opaque_lib_t *const opaque_lib_t_ptr` declaration in `my_struct` with `opaque_lib_t ol;` so the memory layout of `my_struct` will be completely the same as `opaque_lib_t` and `opaque_lib_t*` and `my_struct*` can be cast to each other safely. Is that correct?

Comment: @St.Antario Yes your understanding is correct. However that requires you to have the full definition of `opaque_lib_t`, which is kind of pointless for a truly opaque data structure.